# Can I put a button that automatically inputs GPS coordinates into a google form? (or other spreadsheet populator)

Tags: gps, excel, google-forms

I am currently creating a Google Form and part of the questionnaire requires the user's current GPS location. Is it possible for a button to be able to do this and automatically populate the field? Or is there another way to do this without Google Forms but still can export to Excel?

Comment: This is a good question, does anyone have ideas?

Comment: I dont'd know if it is possible to insert the coordinates from inside the forms, but there is an android app called [AnywhereGIS](http://rockwellspatial.com/anywhere-gis-android.htm) that doest it. I have been using it for few months now, and it's worth every penny. It is working without any problems.